# Issue in calling UIViewController view as subview in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, addsubview

I am implementing [MDSpreadView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdspreadview--2), a third party controller, in one of my projects. I have simply included every file related to it including xib. Calling it as subview.

The hierarchy of calling views is like this: there is a uiviewcontroller in which I am adding UIView as subview, and from that subview I am calling uiviewcontroller as subview.

```
     MDViewController *MDvc = [[MDViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MDViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil ];
     [self addSubview:MDvc.view];
```

It Appears fine but when I touch to scroll or select or for anything, `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error occurs at selection delegate. Whereas delegates are implemented as it is in demo proj.

here is the image
[image]

I know there is some issue in calling subviews. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of taking a view out of one controller and inserting it as a subview in a different controller is a common cause of crashes.  If you have to do it, make sure that the original controller (`MDViewController` in this case) is not released.  You can do that by making it a strong property of the object that is hijacking its view or, better, look at the documentation for how to implement a container controller.

Comment: I am doing research on it thanks for pointing me in correct direction. If u can help me with some good stuff your efforts will b highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally get to know how to handle multiple views, especially when you have subviews and viewcontroller. Solution is very simple , in such situations you need to have delegates or there is a great thing which apple gives itself is NSNotification. I did solve my problem through NSNotification. On the button press(from where i have to call other view)  i post a notification like this:

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"WhatEverYouWantTocallIt" object:nil];
```

and i added observer in the class which i needed to call, like this:

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(bringSpreadViewToFront) name:@"WhatEverYouWantTocallIt" object:nil];
```

AND added a selector, in selector u should handle it according to scenario you have i did this:

-(void)bringSpreadViewToFront{

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

MDViewController *md = [[MDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MDViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];


    [self presentViewController:md animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

i first removed the subviews one by one and then present my view controller, presenting pushing its your choice. it works perfect.. Cheers :)

Thank you Phillip for pushing me in a direction close to the solution.